# DATEADD() function to find values in this business day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, dateadd, getdate

How can I use the SQL DATEADD() function to find a record from this business day? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM records r
WHERE r.creationTime <= GETDATE()
  AND r.creationTime >= DATEADD(dd, -1 * hoursFromStartOfThisDay, GETDATE())
```

Where 'hoursFromStartOfThisDay' is exactly what it says.

Note: I'm talking about business days so from 9am-5pm, Monday-Friday if that matters at all.

Thanks, guys!

Edit: I am also looking to apply a solution to this for the start of the beginning of the week/month and maybe hour too.

Edit: So if a record was created at 18/07/2011 08:55:00 and another created at 18/07/2011 09:05:00, I want the second record to be picked up by the query and not the first. However if the current GETDATE() is 18/07/2011 09:15:00 then it gets tricky.

how about adding `AND r.creationTime >= '9am'`?

Comment: What is "hoursFromStartOfThisDay" means to be? The name *isn't*  useful to us. And datatype of time? "time"? And because it isn't clear, sample data please

Comment: Are you attempting to find a calculation to give "9am today"?  How do you want to treat the following times?  23:59, 00:00, 00:01, 08:59, 17:01?

Comment: -1 Your question update makes this more vague than before

Comment: Is `creationTime > GETDATE()` really possible in your schema?

Comment: Fair enough gbn but sll got it so couldn't have been that vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really need a `hoursFromStartOfThisDay` variable?
If your day is static, from 9 to 5, you can use just this static range:

```sql
-- cache current date to avoid multiple calls
DECLARE @startOfADay INT
DECLARE @dayLength INT
DECLARE @currentDate DATETIME
SET @currentDate = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
SET @startOfADay = 9
SET @dayLength = 8

SELECT 
   ...
FROM
   ...
WHERE ...
BETWEEN 
      DATEADD(hh, @startOfADay, @currentDate) 
      AND 
      DATEADD(hh, @startOfADay + @dayLength, @currentDate)
```

Comment: I thought of that and that would work fine. However, I was using this as a basic example and then going to apple the solution to finding records between the start of the week/month and 'now' too. I'll edit the question to include that.

Comment: Nice to hear, so I answered your question?

Comment: Hi sll, thanks for the code. Trying it now. I believe you have answered my question, yes.